# numpy vectorized: check if strings in array end with strings in another array

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

I have two arrays containing strings. For each string in the one array, I want to check whether it ends in the strings in the second array.

Input:

```
strings = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
ends = ['1', '2', 'al1']
```

Desired output:

```
[[ True, False,  True],
 [False,  True, False],
 [False, False, False]]
```

As `val1` ends in `1` as well as in `al1`, both (0,0) and (0,2) are true.

I have the following working code:

```
import numpy as np

strings = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
ends = ['1', '2', 'al1']

def buildFunction(ending):
    return lambda x: x.endswith(ending)

funcs = list(map(buildFunction, ends))

def end_function_vector(val):
    return np.vectorize(lambda f, x: f(x))(funcs, np.repeat(val, len(funcs)))

result = np.array(list(map(end_function_vector, strings)))
```

And it returns the desired output.

However, for large arrays (~10<sup>9</sup> output elements) the `map` in the last line takes quite a while, since `np.vectorize` and `map` are pretty much just a wrapper around a for-loop. Does anyone know of a faster, vectorized method to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy has these kind of operations for chararrays: `numpy.core.defchararray.endswith()`.

The following bit of code speeds things up quite a bit, but it does take a lot of memory as you create two arrays of the same size as your output array:

```
A = np.array(['val1', 'val2', 'val3'])
B = np.array(['1', '2', 'al1'])

A_matrix = np.repeat(A[:, np.newaxis], len(B), axis=1)
B_matrix = np.repeat(B[:, np.newaxis], len(A), axis=1).transpose()

result = np.core.defchararray.endswith(A_matrix, B_matrix)
```

**Update:**
As Divakar noted, the above code can be consolidated into:

```
A = np.array(['val1', 'val2', 'val3'])
B = np.array(['1', '2', 'al1'])

np.core.defchararray.endswith(A[:,None], B)
```

Comment: Think you can simply do : `np.core.defchararray.endswith(A[:,None], B)` and we have a winner!

Comment: Great implementation! It works up to 4 to 5 times faster than the OP's base.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an almost* vectorized approach making use of [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
# Get lengths of strings in each array
lens_strings = np.array(list(map(len,strings)))
lens_ends = np.array(list(map(len,ends)))

# Get the right most index of match, add the ends strings.
# The matching ones would cover the entire lengths of strings.
# So, do a final comparison against those lengths.
rfind = np.core.defchararray.rfind
out = rfind(strings[:,None], ends) + lens_ends == lens_strings[:,None]
```

Sample run -

```
In [224]: strings = np.array(['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val1y', 'val341'])
     ...: ends = np.array(['1', '2', 'al1', 'l2'])
     ...: 

In [225]: out
Out[225]: 
array([[ True, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

*Almost because of the use of `map`, but since we are only using it to get the lengths of the strings of the input elements, its cost must be minimal in comparison to the other operations needed to solve our case.

Comment: Nice, but it does take up to two times the working memory space.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe I think OP meant vectorized. Parallel would mean staying in Python, but using parallel architectures. The question doesn't look like it.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac Just one time, because we are adding into the indices obtained from `rfind`.

Comment: I did indeed mean vectorized instead of parallel, I have updated the question.

Comment: I get the cool trick, just wanted a heads-up on the *~10^9*. Duplicating such a size cannot be taken lightly. But then again, that's how size-memory tradeoff in algorithms go.